# How do you properly index data in elasticsearch, find it, and then delete it, all using CURL?

Tags: curl, indexing, elasticsearch

I've created code (in a `test.sh` shell script) that tries to test indexing, searching, and deleting of data into an elasticsearch cluster called `my_test_cluster`:

1. Puts two records of type "person" (Jane and John) into an index called `megacorp`.
   NOTE: I believe this is where the code is failing.
2. I search for all records and none of the records I tried to index show up.
   RESULT: I do not see the two records I tried to index but I do see the default record that comes with the instance of elasticsearch (name=Leonus) does show up.
3. I specifically search for user=Jane and nothing comes up.
   RESULT: I do not see a record for user=Jane.
4. I try to delete user=Jane record by her ID=1
5. I search for all records, again, and only see the default record of user=Leonus

My code is as follows:

```
echo ""
echo "------------------------------------------------------"
echo "PUT Employees into megacorp index."
echo "------------------------------------------------------"
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/megacorp/employee/1' -d '{
    "first_name" : "Jane",
    "last_name" :  "Doe",
    "age" :        25,
    "about" :      "I love to go rock climbing and write music.",
    "interests": [ "sports", "music" ]
}'

curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/megacorp/employee/2' -d '{
    "first_name" : "John",
    "last_name" :  "Smith",
    "age" :        30,
    "about" :      "I love to go rock climbing and cooking.",
    "interests": [ "sports", "cooking" ]
}'

echo ""
echo ""
echo "------------------------------------------------------"
echo "Search all records"
echo "------------------------------------------------------"
curl -i -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/'

echo ""
echo ""
echo "------------------------------------------------------"
echo "Search specifically for user = Jane"
echo "------------------------------------------------------"
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/megacorp/employee/_search?q=user:Jane'

echo ""
echo ""
echo "------------------------------------------------------"
echo "Delete employee record ID = 1'"
echo "------------------------------------------------------"

curl -XDELETE 'http://localhost:9200/megacorp/employee/1'

echo ""
echo ""
echo "------------------------------------------------------"
echo "Search all"
echo "------------------------------------------------------"
curl -i -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/'

echo ""
echo ""
```

When I run the script `. test.sh`, I get the following results...

```
------------------------------------------------------
PUT Employees into megacorp index.
------------------------------------------------------
{"_index":"megacorp","_type":"employee","_id":"1","_version":1,"_shards":{"total":2,"successful":1,"failed":0},"created":true}{"_index":"megacorp","_type":"employee","_id":"2","_version":5,"_shards":{"total":2,"successful":1,"failed":0},"created":false}

------------------------------------------------------
Search all records
------------------------------------------------------
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 317

{
  "name" : "Leonus",
  "cluster_name" : "my_test_cluster",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "2.1.0",
    "build_hash" : "72cd1f1a3eee09505e036106146dc1949dc5dc87",
    "build_timestamp" : "2015-11-18T22:40:03Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "5.3.1"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}


------------------------------------------------------
Search specifically for user = Jane
------------------------------------------------------
{"took":7,"timed_out":false,"_shards":{"total":5,"successful":5,"failed":0},"hits":{"total":0,"max_score":null,"hits":[]}}

------------------------------------------------------
Delete employee record ID = 1'
------------------------------------------------------
{"found":true,"_index":"megacorp","_type":"employee","_id":"1","_version":2,"_shards":{"total":2,"successful":1,"failed":0}}

------------------------------------------------------
Search all
------------------------------------------------------
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 317

{
  "name" : "Leonus",
  "cluster_name" : "my_test_cluster",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "2.1.0",
    "build_hash" : "72cd1f1a3eee09505e036106146dc1949dc5dc87",
    "build_timestamp" : "2015-11-18T22:40:03Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "5.3.1"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

Any help on what I'm doing wrong is greatly appreciated.  -- Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query for searching all the records should be either one of (i.e. you need to query the [`/_search` endpoint](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-search.html) not the root `/` which simply tells you some details about your ES install):

```
curl -i -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/megacorp/employee/_search'
curl -i -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/megacorp/_search'
curl -i -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/_search'
```

And you'll see your two records after indexing them. If not you might need to call [`_refresh`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-refresh.html) after indexing and before searching:

```
curl -XPOST 'http://localhost:9200/megacorp/_refresh'
```

In order to search for Jane, you need to use the proper field (`first_name` not `user`), i.e.

```
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/megacorp/employee/_search?q=first_name:jane'
```

You can also search without specifying a field at all (the search will be done on a [special field called `_all`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.7/mapping-all-field.html)):

```
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/megacorp/employee/_search?q=jane'
```

**UPDATE**

I'm answering your comment here as there's more room :)

1. There is no default user "Leonus". What you see there when querying `http://localhost:9200/` is Elasticsearch basically saying "hello world". "Leonus" is just the name of your node. If you restart your node, you'll see another name ([more info](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.7/setup-configuration.html#node-name)).
2. A refresh is happening every second by default, so you only need to call it if you're searching right after indexing in a script. But if you index a document and search it more than a second later, you don't need to refresh it. If you don't want to refresh explicitely, you have two options: 1) you make your script pause for one second (e.g. `sleep 1`) or 2) you set the refresh interval to -1 ([more info](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/near-real-time.html#refresh-api))

Comment: That all seems to work, nicely.  Thank you.  Two short follow up questions: 1) What happened to the default user=Leonus?  I don't see that record anymore but did nothing to specifically eliminate it.  2) Do I always need to refresh after a put or delete?  I noticed that after the delete I had to refresh, as well, to see accurate results. -- Thx

Comment: You're answers make things very clear.  I appreciate your effort.

Comment: Thank you, always glad to help! Don't hesitate if you have other questions.